# I ran an ANN model and got an extremely low R2 but a pretty good MSE, what does this mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, r-squared, mse

I ran an artificial neuron network on data with about 2,000 rows and 3 features. I got a R2 of .06 which is really low, but a good MSE of .41. Why are these performance evaluators of this model contradicting? ..Or what does this tell me about my model?

Answer (score 1):

Note: MSE depends on the scale of your predicted variable, so stateing its value (0.41) does not bring much info. (If you are working on classification problem, cross entropy would be a better criterial function than MSE).
R2 measure the improvement of your model over always predicting the average value of your predicted variable. If you think that your MSE is good, low R2 may be caused by inbalanced dataset: if most of the observation have the same / similar value of predicted variable, then guessing always the average would be a good strategy (and your model will not be able to improve much over it, hence the low R2).